# Plotting piecewise functions using Matplotlib

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib

**ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()**

The above error is what I got for the below code intended to plot the piecewise function created. Can't figure it out.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def f(x):
    if x>=0 and x<=1:
        return x
    elif x>1 and x<=2:
        return 2-x
    else:
        return 0

xlist = np.linspace(0,1,num = 1000)
ylist = f(xlist)

plt.plot(ylist,xlist)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Your function should handle vectorial input. You need to use vectorial operations ;)

Answer (score 1):

As per comments, you need to vectorize your method `f` (and also fix some mistakes):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def f(x):
    y = np.empty_like(x)
    mask1 = (0 <= x) & (x <= 1)
    mask2 = (1 < x) & (x <= 2)
    mask3 = np.logical_not((0 <= x) & (x <= 2)) #or ~((0 <= x) & (x <= 2))
    y[mask1] = x[mask1]
    y[mask2] = 2 - x[mask2]
    y[mask3] = 0
    return y

xlist = np.linspace(-1, 3, num = 1000)
ylist = f(xlist)

plt.plot(xlist, ylist)
plt.show()
```

You might also find that `mask3` is not necessarry and vectorize a method `f` like this:

```
def f(x):
    y = np.full_like(x, fill_value=0) #or np.zeros_like(x)
    mask1 = (0 <= x) & (x <= 1)
    mask2 = (1 < x) & (x <= 2)
    y[mask1] = x[mask1]
    y[mask2] = 2 - x[mask2]
    return y
```

[image]

Comment: Sometimes you wouldn't need to create a mask number `3` (and use `y = np.zeros_like(x)` instead). I've implemented it in a way that works in a more general way assuming OP would want to pad remaining values with anything else than zeros.

Answer (score 0):

What I understood is , you are basically comparing an array with a number which should not be the case here, the code provided might help you with solution,

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def f(x):
    if x>=0 and x<=1:
        return x
    elif x>1 and x<=2:
        return 2-x
    else:
        return 0

xlist = np.linspace(0,1,num = 1000,endpoint=False)
ylist = np.array([f(num) for num in xlist])

plt.plot(xlist,ylist)
plt.show()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function you have already defined and vectorize is using `np.vectorize`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    def f(x):
    if x>=0 and x<=1:
        return x
    elif x>1 and x<=2:
        return 2-x
    else:
        return 0.    # make this change to ensure float values

xlist = np.linspace(0,1,num = 1000)
ylist = np.vectorize(f)(xlist)

plt.plot(ylist,xlist)
plt.show()
```

The issue you are running into in your code is that you are passing an array to `f` rather than applying `f` element-wise, so any comparison gives an array of `True` or `False` values; this is what is ambiguous in the error message. Using `np.vectorize` will change the function defined to apply to each element of the array and give you the desired output.